# Output multiple records php

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I think I just set up my MySQL table poorly. I id, other stuff that doesnt matter, then, movielink1, movielink2, movielink3, movielink4, movielink5

I want a button to appear for each one, ONLY if the movielink# exists. Most of them just have only movielink1 filled.

I think im just looking at it the wrong way. Here's my code.

```
             <?php 
            $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT movielink1,movielink2,movielink3,movielink4,movielink5 FROM movies WHERE id=$id");
            if (mysql_num_rows($data2) > 0 ) {
            while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array($data2)) {
                Print '<a href="'.$info['movielink1'];.'?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="'.$info['title'];.'"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
                }
            } else {
                Print 'Error!'; 
            }
            ?>
```

Thanks for suggestions, I just added this, but its still not working correctly, nor is a great way to approach it.

```
        $data1 = mysql_query("SELECT movielink1 FROM movies WHERE id=$id");
        if (mysql_num_rows($data1) > 0 ) {
        while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array($data1)) {
            Print '<a href="'.$info['movielink1'].'?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="'.$info['title'].'"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
            }
        } else {
        }

        $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT movielink2 FROM movies WHERE id=$id");
        if (mysql_num_rows($data2) > 0 ) {
        while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array($data2)) {
            Print '<a href="'.$info['movielink2'].'?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="'.$info['title'].'"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
            }
        } else {
        }
        $data3 = mysql_query("SELECT movielink3 FROM movies WHERE id=$id");
        if (mysql_num_rows($data3) > 0 ) {
        while($info3 = mysql_fetch_array($data3)) {
            Print '<a href="'.$info['movielink3'].'?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="'.$info['title'].'"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
            }
        } else {
        }
        $data4 = mysql_query("SELECT movielink4 FROM movies WHERE id=$id");
        if (mysql_num_rows($data4) > 0 ) {
        while($info4 = mysql_fetch_array($data4)) {
            Print '<a href="'.$info['movielink4'].'?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="'.$info['title'].'"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
            }
        } else {
        }
        $data5 = mysql_query("SELECT movielink5 FROM movies WHERE id=$id");
        if (mysql_num_rows($data5) > 0 ) {
        while($info5 = mysql_fetch_array($data5)) {
            Print '<a href="'.$info['movielink5'].'?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="'.$info['title'].'"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
            }
        } else {
        }
```

Comment: `if (!empty($info2['movielink1'])){ echo your link here }`. Also `Print` should be [print](http://www.php.net/print) *Case Sensitive*

Comment: Where is `title` coming from?

Comment: Remove `;` From `$info['movielink1'];` & `$info['title'];` otherwise it will throw error http://codepad.org/xSyUAXwS

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but still not working, I just need to check if each record exists. movielink1, movielink2,....movielink5. I added what I tried but that is outputing all 5 buttons still even if only movielink1 is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of little problems in your code. Such as you fetch the row from results and set it to `$info2` but then you call `$info`.

Here is your code fixed up:

```
$sqlResults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id=$id");

if (mysql_num_rows($sqlResults) > 0 ) {
    while($sqlRow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlResults)) {
        if (!empty($sqlRow['movielink1'])) {
            print '<a href="' . $sqlRow['movielink1'] . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="' . $sqlRow['title'] . '"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
        }
        if (!empty($sqlRow['movielink2'])) {
            print '<a href="' . $sqlRow['movielink2'] . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="' . $sqlRow['title'] . '"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
        }
        if (!empty($sqlRow['movielink3'])) {
            print '<a href="' . $sqlRow['movielink3'] . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="' . $sqlRow['title'] . '"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
        }
        if (!empty($sqlRow['movielink4'])) {
            print '<a href="' . $sqlRow['movielink4'] . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="' . $sqlRow['title'] . '"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
        }
        if (!empty($sqlRow['movielink5'])) {
            print '<a href="' . $sqlRow['movielink5'] . '?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="' . $sqlRow['title'] . '"><img src="http://tipmypicks.com/cssmovie/images/watchmovie.png" class="watchmovie"></a>';
        }

    }
} 
else 
{
    print 'Error!'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes so many reasons why my code was terrible. Thank you for this though, it works.

Comment: Happy to help. The problems are just little things. Don't be so hard on yourself. Keep learning.